# Can't connect to MS SQL Server HA Listener

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

We have 2 MS SQL machines behind a HA Group Listener to direct traffic to the current active DB. I'd like to use the HA URL to be able to connect to the machine to upload some files.

HA Listener:

- database.example.com

Machines:

- machine1.example.com
- machine2.example.com

If I do an nslookup on database.example.com I get 2 IP addresses

```
C:\Users\me>nslookup database.example.com
Server:  dns.example.com
Address:  9.1.123.456

Name:    database.example.com
Addresses:  15.25.123.456
          15.25.987.456
```

If I try and navigate to \\database.example.com\C$ in Windows Explorer I get an error that Windows cannot access the machine. If use an IP (15.25.123.456\C$) I get prompted for credentials and can successfully log in.

What is really confusing me is that I can connect via Windows Remote Desktop Connection to database.example.com and it correctly resolves me to the active machine.

Why can I connect via RDP but not as a UNC path in Windows Explorer?

Comment: It could be a lot of things, DSN or maybe Kerberos. Maybe double check the path with your DBA.